# Best way to use Jenkinsfile to run salt command

Tags: jenkins, salt-stack, jenkins-pipeline

I started to work with [`Jenkinsfile`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/jenkinsfile/) and the [pipeline plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Plugin) lately and I was wondering what would be the best way to ask my salt master server to run a command when tests have passed or when we merge a pull request for example.

There is this [jenkinsci/saltstack-plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/saltstack-plugin) that works great (doesn't handle colored output, but it's ok).

1. a. **Would it be better to run the salt step within a `Jenkinsfile`?**
   b. **What would be the syntax to interact with the above plugin?**
2. Or **should I setup my Salt master** (which is on a different server) **as a jenkins slave node** and have the command executed on the salt master directly.

Draft here:

```
node("salt-master") {
    sh "salt -E 'some.target.*' state.sls some.state"
}
```

I think the option 2 would work, but I haven't setup the master as e jenkins slave yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an update to an older post, but in case it helps anyone, the syntax for the saltplugin as a step in a JenkinsFile is given on the jenkins wiki: 
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/saltstack-plugin

Something like the following will give you prettyprint json output

```
import groovy.json.*

node() {
  saltresult = salt authtype: 'pam', clientInterface: local(arguments: '"ls -la"', blockbuild: true,
function: 'cmd.run', jobPollTime: 16, target: '*', targetType: 'glob'),
credentialsId: 'a3d814c2-84ed-4752-94a8-271791bb5375', servername: 'http://localhost:8000'
  def prettyJson = JsonOutput.prettyPrint(saltresult)
  println(prettyJson)
}
```

A benefit of using the jenkins plugin is that you can access other salt-api endpoints such as hook. We have our jenkins server on an internal network which is unable to reach the internet, but our saltmaster is on another network and is able to get out. In our JenkinsFiles we can then send a salt hook call, which kicks a reactor on the saltmaster to send a notification to Slack or MS Teams. Thus, our jenkins server is able to post build status to internet services, without itself being able to access the internet.

Comment: Oh great, I'm still maintaining the jenkins server and the salt minions. I kept the commands as manual shell commands since it worked, but output wasn't really fun.  I will definitely use the plugin now that it supports `Jenkinsfile` syntax. Thanks a lot for your answer. I will also give `hook` calls and `reactor` a try, a very powerful feature I didn't explore yet :)

Answer (score 2):

Both `Jenkins` and `SaltStack` are in the core of our CI/CD processes. `Jenkins` is responsible for artifcats (`deb`s, `rpm`s, Docker images, static files etc.), while `SaltStack` performs deployment of the artifacts among our cluster. `Jenkins` cluster and `SaltMaster` live on different hosts.

Unfortunately I'm not aware neither of `Jenkinsfile` (we're bound to use `Jenkins 1.x` at the moment), nor of the option of turning `SaltMaster` into `Jenkins` slave. Currently our CD consists of a few dozens of distinct `Jenkins` jobs (by a number of microservices we have in our backend) which are triggered by correspondent upstream build jobs. Every deployment job has a `saltstack-plugin` step inside it.

`SaltMaster` provides an entrypoint on a distinct port - `SaltApi`. May be some part of our `/etc/salt/master` could be useful:

```
external_auth:
  pam:
    jenkins:
    - .*

rest_cherrypy:
  port: 8001
  host: 0.0.0.0
```

So in our case `Jenkins` authenticates to `SaltMaster` via `SaltAPI` and launches common salt rpcs among the cluster. There are no pipelines since our project is too complex and pipelines don't fit good.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this, we will definitely look into using `rest_cherrypy`. I'm still unsure if it's easier for us to go with a slave or the `SaltApi`, but it's indeed a good idea to communicate directly with the api for deployments.